# How to convert CFString to HFSUniStr255?

Tags: c++, c, macos, macos-carbon, codewarrior

First things first, this relates to ancient technology. The program port I'm working on is maintained in Metrowerks Codewarrior 9, target is PPC.

For use in MSL C's FSRefParentAndFilename_fopen function

```
FILE * FSRefParentAndFilename_fopen(
const FSRefPtr theParentRef,
ConstHFSUniStr255Param theName,
const char *open_mode);
```

I need a ConstHFSUniStr255Param which is a pointer to a HFSUniStr255.
I have a CFString containing my filename, my question is how do I convert to HFSUniStr255?

```
struct HFSUniStr255 {
UInt16 length;
UniChar unicode[255];
};
```

So far I have:

```
HFSUniStr255 HFSString;
FSGetDataForkName(&HFSString);
HFSString.length=(uint16)CFStringGetLength(fileName);
HFSString.unicode=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
HFSString.length=(uint16)CFStringGetLength(fileName);
CFStringGetCharacters(filename, CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(filename)), HFSString.unicode);
```

Be sure however that your filename is valid, and in particular that its length is less than 255 Unicode characters. You will have to face the consequences of a buffer overflow otherwise.